# Renaming files from shell by removing letters

Tags: linux, shell

I have a lot of jpg files with letters and numbers in their names. I want to remove all letters, for example `abc12d34efg.jpg` becomes `1234.jpg`. For the for loop I thought:

```
 for i in *.jpg; do mv "$i" ...
```

but I can't find a command for what I want.

Comment: A bit out of topic, but can be useful: there is a command named mmv, which serves your goal, without risk of data loss.

Answer (score 1):

With shell parameter expansion:

```
for fname in *.jpg; do mv "$fname" "${fname//[[:alpha:]]}jpg"; done
```

`"${fname//[[:alpha:]]}"` is a substitution of all occurrences of `[[:alpha:]]` (any letter) with nothing. Because this also removes the `jpg`, we have to add it again – the appended `jpg` does that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed to replace all letters with nothing using regex.

```
for i in *.jpg; do mv $i `echo $i | sed -e 's/[a-zA-Z]//g'`jpg; done
```

Comment: Would fail if the filename contains spaces

Answer (score 0):

Here is a oneline solution that uses `tr`

```
 for f in *.jpg ; do n="$(echo ${f} | tr -d a-zA-Z )" ; mv "$f" "${n}jpg" ; done
```

With some formatting it would look like as

```
 for f in *.jpg ; do 
   n="$(echo ${f} | tr -d a-zA-Z )" 
   mv "$f" "${n}jpg"
 done
```

Here is what's happening:

First we remove all letters from the name using `tr -d a-zA-Z`. From `abc12d34efg.jpg` we get `1234.` (with a dot at the end as `.` does not belong in the `a-z` and `A-Z` intervals) and assign this value to variable `$n`. T

Then we can rename `$f` to `${n}jpg`. That's it.

**Update** to delete both lower case and upper case letters use `tr -d a-zA-Z`, to delete only lower case letters use `tr -d a-z` instead.

Comment: Thank you! It works but I had to execute another cicle for upper case letters, Anyway very good explanation!

Comment: @druido82 Welcome to Stack Overflow. If an answer solved your problem you are welcome to accept it by ticking the check mark next to the answer.